# Universal package manager for install/uninstall?

Tags: package-management

All I truly want a package manager for is to install an app in a location of my choice, make symlinks if I want them, and remove everything when I'm done with the app. Keeping track of all the user-modifiable files for each app and saving those when I "remove" would be nice too.

Yet there are 5-10 different package managers each with their own "ecosystem" of apps, and there are also a lot of apps I come across while browsing the web that say "here, download this .tgz!"; sure I'll click, but now I have a .tgz!

Does anything sort of like a "universal" package manager exist? Something with few features, just install and uninstall would be perfect as long as it will install/uninstall whatever I throw at it: .deb, .rpm, .tgz, .gem, etc.

All I want is install/uninstall through a single interface, a la App Store!

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I've seen to what you're asking for is a project I found a while back on github called `fpm`. Stands for Effing Package Manager.

- https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

Sources:

- gem (even autodownloaded for you)
- python modules (autodownload for you)
- pear (also downloads for you)
- directories
- rpm
- deb
- node packages (npm)

Targets:

- deb
- rpm
- solaris
- tar
- directories

The app `fpm` is a Ruby gem so you install it like so:

```
$ gem install fpm
```

Once installed you can build a package as follows:

```
 $ fpm -s <source type> -t <target type> [list of sources]...
```